# If Bootstrap class loader is responsible for loading classes from rt.jar then why String.class.getClassloader returns null

Tags: java, classloader

I am trying to understand how class loaders work in java. As far as I understand the topmost class loader i.e. Bootstrap class loader is responsible for loading all the classes from rt.jar. If I call String.class.getClassloader the result is null. Isn't it supposed to return an instance of bootstrap class loader?

Comment: The javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) says: *Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.*

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks. This answers my question. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) says:

> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.